# Dynamic Forms with Angular 2 MongoDB and WebAPI

Tags: mongodb, angular, angular-reactive-forms

This is not just a Dynamic Reactive Forms.

**Usage**

I want to Generate controls dynamically in forms based on values in database.Controls can vary from Dropdown, TextArea, Input etc, the type of control is specified in database and will get a json like this

```
{
    "Controls": [{
            "controlid": "24",
            "controltype": "textarea",
            "controlname": "textarea24",
            "validations": {
                "Required": "true",
                "MaxLength": "100",
                "MinLength": "2"
            }
        },
        {
            "controlid": "25",
            "controltype": "select",
            "controlname": "select25",
            "validations": {
                "Required": "false",
                "MaxLength": "0",
                "MinLength": "0"
            }
        },
        {
            "controlid": "26",
            "controltype": "radio",
            "controlname": "radio26",
            "validations": {
                "Required": "true",
                "MaxLength": "0",
                "MinLength": "0"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can i acheive this using Angular 4 and also want to submit that generated form.

Comment: You have to make a component that takes this json configuration in input and then does an ngFor with some ngSwitch for each type and puts HTML based on the json, pretty long to write as a response on stackoverflow

Comment: @GianlucaParis how form posting can be done with it